# shell script doesn't run correctly in cron

Tags: linux, cron, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [shell script doesn't run correctly in cron](https://serverfault.com/questions/288408/shell-script-doesnt-run-correctly-in-cron)

I want to call a shell script I wrote from a cron. The shell script uses the program Linkchecker. If I run the shell script from the terminal it works just fine. However, when cron runs I get the following errors:

> File
>   "/Users/keith/etc/cron/linkchecker",
>   line 40, in 
>       from linkcheck.director import console, check_urls, get_aggregate
>   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import aggregator, console   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/aggregator.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import logger, status, checker, cleanup   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/status.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       from . import task   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/task.py", line 20, in 
>       from . import console   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/console.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       stderr = codecs.getwriter(i18n.default_encoding)(sys.stderr,
>   errors="ignore")   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/codecs.py",
>   line 930, in getwriter
>       return lookup(encoding).streamwriter
>   LookupError: unknown encoding: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/keith/etc/cron/linkchecker",
>   line 40, in 
>       from linkcheck.director import console, check_urls, get_aggregate
>   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import aggregator, console   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/aggregator.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import logger, status, checker, cleanup   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/status.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       from . import task   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/task.py", line 20, in 
>       from . import console   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/console.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       stderr = codecs.getwriter(i18n.default_encoding)(sys.stderr,
>   errors="ignore")   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/codecs.py",
>   line 930, in getwriter
>       return lookup(encoding).streamwriter
>   LookupError: unknown encoding: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/keith/etc/cron/linkchecker",
>   line 40, in 
>       from linkcheck.director import console, check_urls, get_aggregate
>   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import aggregator, console   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/aggregator.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import logger, status, checker, cleanup   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/status.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       from . import task   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/task.py", line 20, in 
>       from . import console   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/console.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       stderr = codecs.getwriter(i18n.default_encoding)(sys.stderr,
>   errors="ignore")   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/codecs.py",
>   line 930, in getwriter
>       return lookup(encoding).streamwriter
>   LookupError: unknown encoding: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/keith/etc/cron/linkchecker",
>   line 40, in 
>       from linkcheck.director import console, check_urls, get_aggregate
>   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import aggregator, console   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/aggregator.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import logger, status, checker, cleanup   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/status.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       from . import task   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/task.py", line 20, in 
>       from . import console   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/console.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       stderr = codecs.getwriter(i18n.default_encoding)(sys.stderr,
>   errors="ignore")   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/codecs.py",
>   line 930, in getwriter
>       return lookup(encoding).streamwriter
>   LookupError: unknown encoding: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/keith/etc/cron/linkchecker",
>   line 40, in 
>       from linkcheck.director import console, check_urls, get_aggregate
>   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import aggregator, console   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/aggregator.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import logger, status, checker, cleanup   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/status.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       from . import task   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/task.py", line 20, in 
>       from . import console   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/console.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       stderr = codecs.getwriter(i18n.default_encoding)(sys.stderr,
>   errors="ignore")   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/codecs.py",
>   line 930, in getwriter
>       return lookup(encoding).streamwriter
>   LookupError: unknown encoding: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/keith/etc/cron/linkchecker",
>   line 40, in 
>       from linkcheck.director import console, check_urls, get_aggregate
>   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import aggregator, console   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/aggregator.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import logger, status, checker, cleanup   File
>   "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/status.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       from . import task   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/task.py", line 20, in 
>       from . import console   File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/linkcheck/director/console.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       stderr = codecs.getwriter(i18n.default_encoding)(sys.stderr,
>   errors="ignore")   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/codecs.py",
>   line 930, in getwriter
>       return lookup(encoding).streamwriter
>   LookupError: unknown encoding:

I have chmod 777 the linkchecker file. I have moved the linkchecker file to my current home directory. I added the cron by saying

```
crontab -e
```

I put in

```
38       12      *       *       5      /Users/keith/etc/cron/linkchecker.sh
```

The first line of my shell script is #!/bin/sh

So the only thing I can think of is I'm missing some environment variables when cron runs. When I add env at the top of my script and compare the variables from when cron runs versus from the terminal there is a difference. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694942/environment-variable-used-in-shell-script-appear-blank-in-log-file-when-run-by-cr I can add . /etc/profile and that should put in the correct environment variables. This does not appear to be sucking in the variables because the variables are still the same when I use env.

I am on a Mac if that makes any difference. Also I pasted in the working variables at the top of my script that worked when I run from terminal and cron still didn't work.

Comment: Based on the "unknown encoding" error. Try setting the LANG and LC_ALL in your crontab to the same value you use in the terminal. You can use the command `locale` to view this values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
38 12 * * 5 /bin/bash -l -c /Users/keith/etc/cron/linkchecker.sh
```

The `-l` option will get a login environment for executing the script.